# Are there any vampires?

Tags: bon

Are there any vampires in any living or dead (hah!) buddhist tradition?

I read that there were kinda vampires in Tibetan Bon?

Not sure why I'm asking, probably spiritual [ressentiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ressentiment) :)

Peace...

Comment: This is the closes thing i could find on Vampires. VETALA (Skt.): Corpse revived by a bad spirit, zombie.http://viewonbuddhism.org/glossary_az.html

Comment: Why not the reverse question, e.g. something that suggests Vampires, Zombies and ever other western monster myth derive from rakshas, yakshas, hungry ghosts, etc. Sometimes there really are connections, e.g. Thor and Indra are based on the same story because the story traveled with the indoeuropean religion in many directions.

Answer (score 1):

Strangely there is a site about this. Check out [Buddhism for Vampires](http://buddhism-for-vampires.com/the-tibetan-book-of-the-undead). Like Orion says in her comments the tantric beings [Vetala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vetala) could be thought of as vampires or zombies. Certainly they seems to do a lot of hanging around in burial grounds and a bit of drinking of blood. If it looks like a vampire, drinks blood like a vampire then perhaps it is a vampire.

Comment: The [author of that site](http://approachingaro.org/about-the-author) claims [on the about page](http://buddhism-for-vampires.com/), "As it happens, I also have no credentials when it comes to vampires. I don’t like scary movies, and I haven't really read much vampire fiction.
Given that, how I came to be writing a Buddhist vampire romance is one of those inexplicable confluences. Nevertheless, I find the intersection of Buddhism and vampires emotionally gripping and intellectually fascinating. I hope you will too."

Comment: @ChrisW A Buddhist vampire romance might be one for the book club - http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/1500/157. Perhaps?? (perhaps not) :-)

Comment: The 'Genesis of this site' suggests he wrote it to bring Buddhism to ... *Twilight* fans, is it? Goths? Maybe [this other book](http://approachingaro.org/brad-warner) instead, which is something like 'Buddhism for Punks'...

Comment: i am worried about the reliability of this site hehe